# Photobox insert in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

When I run my code on Xampp (localhost), it runs normally. When I go to the server-side to run the same code, it doesn't work with Photobox.

What should I do now? My thought is to combine the two. I am thinking of copying from the Photobox archives into Bootstraps. No idea why it's not working.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mychess.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mychess.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="description" content="Project">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="photobox/photobox.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='photobox/jquery.photobox.js'></script>
```

Comment: Is jquery.photobox.js loading properly on the live site? You'll be able to narrow if your issue is a src location issue, or a code issue.

Comment: it is 50% -50%.On xamp it is 100% my work..on the live site it is 50%

Comment: Not sure I understand your response. Does the photobox script load correctly on live?

Comment: not.it loads only somethings not all.